# Passing parameters to excel query in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I want read a excel file using OleDB but when insert a parameter in the query, I have this OleDb exception:

> No value was given for one or more of the required parameters

Code

```
string conn = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";", opFileImport.FileName);

string sql = "Select CODICE_FISCALE From [Parte_4$] ";
sql += "where CODICE_FISCALE = ?";

using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
{
   dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, excelConn);
   dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Param1", strCodFisc));
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name should be **CODICE_FISCALE** instead of <strike>Param1</strike>. Try this code

```
var conn = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";", opFileImport.FileName);
string sql = "Select CODICE_FISCALE From [Parte_4$] ";
sql += "where CODICE_FISCALE = ?";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(conn))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, excelConn);
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("CODICE_FISCALE", strCodFisc));
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```